# Forcing download using <filesMatch> in .htaccess not working just for one filetype

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

Internet Explorer is displaying contents of some files instead of downloading them. I was able to fix this by adding

```
<FilesMatch "\.(asapt|ob2|cub)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

to .htaccess. It works for .asapt and .cub files, but strangely not for .ob2 (they are still being displayed in-browser). Why?

Comment: Try clear browser cache before checking.

Comment: Indeed, clearing cache solved this. Thanks